# Merging rows by mutual attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, merge, attribute-joins, one-to-many

I have a grid as polygons, each square having its own `"ID"`, and several observations for each square. But, I have three categories of observation, each with its own row, matching the same `"ID"`. Here `"gid"` and `"id_carreau"`. I would like to have the three different `"NUMCOUNTS"` on the same row.

My final goal is to create a pie chart for square of the grid, proportional to these categories.

Here is my question, how do I merge these rows? see selected.

[image]

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

You could use the ["Aggregate"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisaggregate) tool from the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) (placed under `Vector geometry > Aggregate`). In *'Group by expression'* enter the `"gid"` field.

Answer (score 4):

You can use ["Merge Attributes of Selected Features"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html?highlight=merge%20attributes%20selected%20features#merge-attributes-of-selected-features) Tool to merge your rows.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS I can suggest using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume there is a point layer called *'grid_test'* with it's attribute table, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible to achieve the result, i.e. to merge rows.

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    geometry AS geom,
    GROUP_CONCAT(attr1) AS attr1,
    GROUP_CONCAT(attr2) AS attr2,
    GROUP_CONCAT(attr3) AS attr3
FROM
    "grid_test"
GROUP BY
    id,
    geometry
```

The output Virtual Layer will look like as following

[image: result]

---

**References:**

- [SQLite GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group_concat/)